# Flutter paint(): is this legit? Rendering Renderobject in different context

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-layout, paint, renderbox

I try to render the child of a listitem (somewhere up) to a different place (widget) in the tree;
In the approach below, `BlendMask` is the "target" widget that checks for and paints "source" widgets that got themself an `GlobalKey` which is stored in `blendKeys`.
This works somewhat. And I'm not quite sure if I might fight the framework, or just missing some points...

The problems are two:

- The minor one: This approach doesn't play nice with the debugger. It compiles and runs fine but every hot-reload (on save f.e.) throws an "can't findRenderObject() of inactive element". Maybe I miss some debug flag?
- the real problem, that brought me here questioning the idea en gros: As mentioned, the `Source`-Widget is somewhere in the subtree of the child of a `Scrollable` (from a `ListView.build` f.e.): How can I update the `Òffset` for the `srcChild.paint()` when the list is scrolled? - *without accessing the lists scrolController?!* I tried listening via `WidgetsBindingObserver`s `didChangeMetrics` on the state of the `Source` widget, but as feared no update on scroll. Maybe a strategically set `RepaintBoundery`is all it needs? *hope* :D

Anyway, every tip much appreciated. Btw the is an extend of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70560544/flutter-renderobject-layer-how-to-render-widgets-on-specific-layers) which itself extends [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70525628/flutter-how-to-stop-imagefilter-colorfilter-paint-filter-at-particular-chil)...

```
class BlendMask extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  [...]
  @override
  RenderObject createRenderObject(context) {
    return RenderBlendMask();
  }
}

class RenderBlendMask extends RenderProxyBox {
[...]
@override
void paint(PaintingContext context, offset) {    <-- the target where we want to render a widget
  [...]                                              from somewhere else in the tree!
  for (GlobalKey key in blendKeys) {
    if (key.currentContext != null) {
      RenderObject? srcChild                     <-- the source we want to render in this sibling widget!
       = key.currentContext!.findRenderObject();
      if (srcChild != null) {
        Matrix4 mOffset = srcChild.getTransformTo(null);
        context.pushTransform(true, offset, mOffset, (context, offset) {
          srcChild.paint(context, offset);
        });
      }
    } 
  }
}
} //RenderBlendMask
```

Comment: you dont need those global keys and painting the other render objects with different paining context: instead you can have the same widgets as children in two different widget tree locations

Comment: ui?! That'd be awesome! Could u lead me to some more info to finde about how in the docs or something?

Comment: thanks for the answer. Though I'm not quite sure I described my problem correctly: Sure I can use a child-widget at multiple places in the widget tree. What I want is to paint a chid where it is "naturally" laid out through it's normal parents bounds but *additionally* render a clone of that child at a totally different place in the tree and all I have to identify that place is a key or a widget type - so I search for a way to programmatically render a given renderobject somewhere else.

Comment: have a look at my previous question, there's a diagram of the tree: In that approach the "MyMagicUnblurer" there is the "Source" I'm trying to render somewhere else.

Comment: and what do you need that `pushTransform` for? why not to call `srcChild.paint(context, offset);` directly?

Comment: because it takes a matrix4 as offset input. ... but that's not the point here. Appreciate your help, but have you read my last two comments?

Comment: Yes, thank you! Now I understand your confusion :D I basically tried to reinvent Overlay in combination with CompositedTransformFollower/Target lol. I will craft an answer to all my questions maybe helping the next lost souls. :D
If you're interested, here's what I was trying to archive: https://pastebin.com/VVztJ910

Comment: do you need that `OverlayEntry` too? i am asking since it could be much more simplified as you have to do a lot of things when using overlay API: getting `OverlayState` / insert / remove / keeping active `OverlayEntry` etc

Comment: I'm afraid it is.. unless you have a better idea: apptree:...-blur-stack-list-item/item/item - can't blur the list items by them selfs, they need to blend together. every item has a component that needs to be lifted above the blurr. that's what this is all this about. If you want, just run the pastebin: pink needs to blur with the list items, every list item has a small indigo rect that needs to be unblured.

Comment: *"can't blur the list items by them selfs"* - i gave you a solution where each item is blurred by a separate `ImageFiltered` widget - you dont need that `Overlay` - everything is done with a `Stack` widget with two children: "blurred" on the bottom and "normal" on the top

Comment: you missed the important part if that sentance: "can't blur the list items by them selfs, _they need to blend together._"